# handleClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a MenuCard component which contains a handleClick which returns the names and images of the various menus. I also have a LikeButton component which has a counter and increments each time the button is pressed.

I am having problems trying to use this LikeButton in the MenuCard as every time I click the button, it goes to the selected menu's id page, which it should do if the user clicks on the card.

But how can I have it avoid that when I click LikeButton? I am just not sure where to call LikeButton in MenuCard.

MenuCard Component:

```
import React from 'react';

import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'

import LikeButton from "../components/LikeButton";

const MenuCard = props => {

    const handleClick = () => {
        props.view(props.info.id, "menus", 'DISPLAY_MENUS');
    };

    return (
        <Card onClick={handleClick} style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{props.info.name}<LikeButton /></Card.Title>
            </Card.Body>
            <Card.Img variant="bottom" style={{ height: '12rem' }} src={props.info.image} />
        </Card>
    )
}

export default MenuCard
```

LikeButton Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

class LikeButton extends Component {
  state = {
      count: 0
    }

increment = () => {
      let newCount = this.state.count + 1
      this.setState({
        count: newCount
      })
    }

render() {
  return (
   <div>
     <button onClick={this.increment}>Likes: {this.state.count} </button>
   </div>
  )
}

}

export default LikeButton;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.stopPropagation` in your `LikeButton` component to prevent `onClick` event from bubbling up to `MenuCard` component:

```js
<button 
  onClick={e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.increment();
  }
>
Likes: {this.state.count}
</button>
```

Comment: I added this to LikeButton but it is still jumping to the menu/:id page whenever I click the button. Maybe I am calling LikeButton in the wrong place in MenuCard?

Comment: It works on this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wood-1gcwy). 
 Clicks on the "Card name" text will increase the count, but clicking on the button only increases it internal state. You can try comment out the e.stopPropagation() in `LikeButton.js` to see the difference

Comment: I can see that the button increments to 1 when I click it but then it abruptly jumps to the menu/:id page which is my MenuDisplay component.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use stop propagation to handle this issue. Instead you can add an id to the like button and check the value of event.target.id in menu click to avoid it triggering.

why should you avoid stop propagation - In case you add a analytics tool to your web page, they rely on event bubbling to capture data.

Comment: Yea, its doing the same thing I mentioned for the stopPropagation answer; "it is still jumping to the menu/:id page whenever I click the button". It is going to the team display page because of the TeamCard's handleClick.